# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist. Occurs persistently on some devices on 'delete'

Tags: swiftui

I built a SwiftUI app that runs smoothly on several devices: iPhone 6s, 6s Plus, 7, 8, two X's.
However there is one iPhone 6s Plus that persistently crashes the app when deleting rows from a list view.

```
var general: Point
@Binding var generalPoints: [Point]

func deleteGeneral(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    if let first = offsets.first {
        let generali = generalPoints[first]
        deletePointFromParse(deletableData: generali)
        generalhPoints.remove(at: first)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach (self.generalPoints) { generali in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(generali.eventReport)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                }
            }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteGeneral)
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("Delete")
    }
}
```

The error message when I hook up the particular iPhone 6s Plus to Xcode 11 GM with a cable:

2019-09-25 20:18:11.040835+0200 Points[392:54213] *** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3899.22.15/UINavigationController.m:7989
2019-09-25 20:18:11.041583+0200 Points[392:54213] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18ef4498c 0x18ec6d0a4 0x18ee46d1c 0x18f27c8f4 0x1928bd8a0 0x1928bd5b8 0x1c41b5364 0x1c41b4880 0x1c4144f2c 0x1c4235924 0x1c459c2bc 0x1c459bd24 0x1c4592600 0x1c4144ce8 0x1c41411b8 0x101361828 0x101362c04 0x101370c64 0x18eec23c4 0x18eebd3b8 0x18eebc8bc 0x198d27328 0x192f516d4 0x100b4db48 0x18ed47460)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

It does not make any difference if I leave out the 'deletePointFromParse' line.

When I run exact the same code on a connected iPhone X, it works fine. I'm quite new at programming and stuck on this inconsistent behavior of my app. Anyone suggestions on how to find the bug?